# Accessing LDAP through SSH tunnel

Tags: networking, tcp, ssh, ldap, firewall

I got access via SSH (root access) to a Machine that's inside a network at my client's office.

I'm programming in my computer a PHP application that needs to integrate to LDAP. The LDAP server is in another server at my client's network and *not* accesible from outside, however I can perfectly access it via the server I can connect to via SSH.

My question is: IS there anyway I can make a tunnel and setup a port in my computer to get the traffic forwarded to the LDAP server using my SSH connection to one of the computers on the network?

Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes, `ssh` has a "`-L`" option to create a tunnel. That option takes 3 parameters, separated by colons (:). Local listen port, remote host, remote port.

```
ssh -L 9999:ldapserver:389 user@otherhost
```

Where 9999 is the local port that the tunnel will be created on. The `ldapserver:389` bit tells it where to connect *to* on the other side.

Then, tell your application to connect to localhost:9999 (or whatever port you choose) and it will be tunneled across.

Comment: you might also use the -N option, so ssh doesn't become interactive

Comment: thanks! I got connection refused although with both optins but this may be another problem

Comment: you need to tcp forwarding enabled on the remote ssh server. By default this is often disabled. In sshd_config put:

AllowTcpForwarding yes