# PHP connect via SSH tunnel to LDAP in other network

Tags: php, ssh, ldap, tunneling

I'm developing website for my school. In that school we authenticate users via LDAP, so there was an idea to do the same via school-site. On that site everything is working perfectly, but during developing I need very often to test if such solution works, of not. In order not to commit my changes so often I want to test this site on my local computer, but for connecting with LDAP i want to use ssh tunnel. In school network we have one server through witch we are connecting with inside of our school network. It's address is `phoenix.lo5.bielsko.pl`. Inside this network we have LDAP server with opened 389 and 636 ports. It's address is `auth.lo5`. I don't have access to `auth.lo5` via SSH, I can only connect with it to get some LDAP entries. So, I've tried to run SSH tunnel by running:

```
ssh -L 636:auth.lo5:636 hfaua@phoenix.lo5.bielsko.pl
```

Then, I've set in my `/etc/hosts` that `auth.lo5` is pointing to `127.0.0.1`. I'm connecting to LDAP in PHP in such a way:

```
ldap_connect('ldaps://auth.lo5', 636);
```

But I'm getting error `Can't contact LDAP server`. I think, that problem might be on `phoenix.lo5.bielsko.pl` in its SSH daemon config or in arguments passed to `ldap_connect()` function. Can you tell me, what should I set in sshd_config or in arguments passed to `ldap_connect` to get it working?

I posted the same question in [similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244717/accessing-ldap-through-ssh-tunnel/), but no one has answered my question.

P.S. In my `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` I have line `AllowTcpForwarding yes`

Comment: If you use the LDAP command-line tools, do they work?  Try using `ldapwhoami -H ldaps://auth.lo5` first - PHP doesn't report as many helpful messages as the command-line LDAP utilities.

Comment: @Borealid, our LDAP server don't allow to bind anonymously, so I've typed `ldapwhoami -D cn=lo5-www,ou=services,dc=auth,dc=lo5 -W -H ldaps://auth.lo5` and on phoenix answer is `dn:cn=lo5-www,ou=services,dc=auth,dc=lo5`, but on my desktop its `ldap_sasl_bind(SIMPLE): Can't contact LDAP server (-1)`

Comment: Until the command-line tools work, your SSH tunnel isn't up.  Since the command you're using is spot-on (and, honestly, I'm *impressed* you know how to do this - SSH tunneling is complicated!), I only have one more suggestion.  Try using an unprivileged port (higher than 1024) for the local port (as in, `ssh -L 9999:auth.lo5.bielsko.pl:636`).  Also specify a FQDN!  Still, test with the command-line tools.  And make sure they work from phoenix.lo5 to auth.lo5!

Answer (score 1):

If I got it right phoenix.lo5 and auth.lo5 are 2 different machines.
If so you have to create a tunnel to the ssh machine, and then send the ldap queries to the right machine.

Your command: `ssh -L 636:auth.lo5:636 hfaua@phoenix.lo5.bielsko.pl` is right if `phoenix.lo5.bielsko.pl` can resolve `auth.lo5` via DNS or /etc/hosts, if not you need to use its internal ip address.

Also if you want to use port 636 on your pc, you need to run your command as superuser (root or with sudo) else you need to use an high port (above 1024) as stated by Borealid

Once the tunnel is up you have to point to localhost to do the queries

Comment: Of course `phoenix` and `auth` are different machines and we use our DNS to resolve its names. I think, addresses aren't real problem here. I've used `tcpdump` to check if there are real connection through tunnel and if `ldapwhoami` is sending packets correctly. The result was confusing: `local =[tunnel]=> phoenix => auth (LDAP querying) => phoenix =[tunnel]=> local`, so I think, that `ldapwhoami` should give right answer, but I get error `ldap_sasl_bind(SIMPLE): Can't contact LDAP server (-1)`. I have sudo on `phoenix` so ports under 1024 are not problem, I think. Don't you think its weird?

Comment: I'm bumping into this same issue. My current thought is that the SSL handshake is failing. I tried using a local /etc/hosts entry to fake out the hostname, but that hasn't worked out yet.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same issue. Running with `-d1` showed me this error:

`TLS: hostname (mylaptop.local) does not match common name in certificate (*.mydomain.com).
TLS reverse lookup of 'localhost' is 'mylaptop.local', checking if that matches the certificate common name`

Could be you're hitting a similar problem.

I was able to fake it out by running:

`sudo hostname someserver.mydomain.com`

which caused SSL to assume it was talking to the right host.

Answer (score 1):

I was also getting the error `hostname (mylaptop.local) does not match common name in certificate (*.mydomain.com)`. However I did not want to edit the hostname of my machine to match that of the LDAP server. Instead I edited the hosts file (`etc/hosts` on linux) file to add a line that would intercept requests to the LDAP server eg:

```
127.0.0.1 ldap.server.com
```

This has the added benefit of not requiring you to change which server name you are trying to connect to in your code, you only need to change the port number if you chose a different port.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing all instances of `auth.lo5` with localhost:

`ssh -L 636:localhost:636 hfaua@phoenix.lo5.bielsko.pl`
and
`ldap_connect('ldaps://localhost', 636);`

If that doesn't work, try turning off SSL to see if that works:

`ssh -L 389:localhost:389 hfaua@phoenix.lo5.bielsko.pl`
and
`ldap_connect('localhost', 389);`

Comment: Both solutions aren't working. I think, it shouldn't be localhost in ssh commands, because LDAP server is reachable for phoenix not by 'localhost' but 'auth.lo5'. 'localhost' points to phoenix. Maybe I have to put something to my client or server ssh-configs?